# Passing data to textarea inside bootstrap modal that uses TINYMCE WYSIWYG

Tags: laravel, tinymce, laravel-5.3, bootstrap-modal, tinymce-4

I am creating a blog now and I want to update a comment,
I want to pass the current data of the comment to the textarea that uses TINYMCE WYSIWYG editor.

The problem is if I use tinymce for the textarea the current data will NOT show on the textarea.

here is how I do it

This is the button that will trigger the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}" data-comment=" {{ $comment->comment }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

This is the modal

```
    <!--UPDATE COMMENT Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade modal-md" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content modal-success">
      {{ Form::open(['route' => ['comments.update'], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h5 class="modal-title"><b>Update Comment </b></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="comment-form" class="">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        {!! Form::hidden('id', '', ['id' => 'comment-id']) !!}

                        {{ Form::textarea('comment', '', ['id'=>'comment-comment','class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3']) }}

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><b>Update</b></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> <b>Cancel</b></button>
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is my js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    statusbar:  false,
     height:     10
  });

<!--UPDATE COMMENT MODAL-->
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
         $("#comment-comment").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('comment'));
         $("#comment-id").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
    });
});

// Prevent bootstrap dialog from blocking focusin
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});

$('#open').click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 800,
        modal: true
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   {!! Form::hidden('id', $data->id , ['id' => 'comment-id']) !!}

   {{ Form::textarea('comment', $data->coment, ['id'=>'comment-comment','class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3']) }}
```

If you are using form open that case you need to specify a value like "$data->coment". And if you are using Form model that case it's not required to specify any value just need to add null. Check below link.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding

Comment: yes it can be, but the problem is it is on modal and I want to return the value of the current comment to the text area that uses text editor, and the problem is there is only one form that can be used by many comments, the current comment value will just send to the form upon clicking the edit button